# Calculating integral $\int_u^1\frac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s-u}}\text{d}s. $

Tags: calculus, integration

I encountered this kind of integral $$\int_u^1\frac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s-u}}\text{d}s. $$ Is there an easy way to calculate it? I checked the integral with mathematica and it gave $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-u)$ as an answer. My integration skills have become pretty rusty, especially in the case of square roots so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Try using $\frac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s-u}}=x$

Comment: I used that substitution but then got integrals of the form $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\text{dx}$, which look as weird to me as the original integral..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{1-s}$ and we have $$\int_u^1\frac{1-s}{\sqrt{s-s^2-u+us}}ds$$

Now split the integral up so there is an integral of the form $\int\frac{Q'}{\sqrt{Q}}=2\sqrt{Q}$ with the left over terms being of the form of an $\arcsin$ integral, after completing the square, and we have $$I=\frac 12\int_u^1\frac{1+u-2s}{\sqrt{s-s^2-u+us}}ds+\frac 12\int_u^1\frac{1-u}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)^2-\left(s-\left(\frac{1+u}{2}\right)\right)^2}}ds$$

So $$I=\left[\sqrt{s-s^2-u+us}\right]^1_u+\left[\frac 12(1-u)\arcsin\left(\frac{s-\left(\frac{1+u}{2}\right)}{\frac{1-u}{2}}\right)\right]^1_u$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-u)$$

Comment: Nice trick indeed.

Answer (score 2):

On the path of Claude Leibovici,

$\displaystyle J=\int_u^1\frac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s-u}}\text{d}s$

$0<u<1$

Perform the change of variable $y=1-s$,

$\begin{align} J&=\int_{0}^{1-u}\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{1-u-s}}\text{d}s\\
&=\int_{0}^{1-u}\frac{\sqrt{\tfrac{s}{1-u}}}{\sqrt{1-\tfrac{s}{1-u}}}\text{d}s\\
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{s}{1-u}$

$\begin{align}J&=(1-u)\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds \tag 1\\
&=(1-u)\text{B}\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=(1-u)\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(2)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-u)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-u)\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-u)
\end{align}$

Alternatives to compute (1):

Perform the change of variable $y=1-s$,

$\displaystyle J=(1-u)\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s}}ds$

Perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{s}$,

$\displaystyle J=2(1-u)\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-s^2}ds$

Perform the change of variable $s=\sin t$,

$\begin{align} J&=2(1-u)\int_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(t)dt\\
&=2(1-u)\left[\dfrac{2x+\sin(2x)}{4}\right]_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-u)
\end{align}$

An other alternative to compute $(1)$.

in $(1)$ perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{\dfrac{s}{1-s}}$

$\displaystyle J=(1-u)\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{2s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}ds$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{s}$,

$\displaystyle J=(1-u)\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{(1+s^2)^2}ds$

Therefore,

$\begin{align} 2J&=(1-u)\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{2+2s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}ds\\
&=(1-u)\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{1+s^2}ds\\
&=2(1-u)\Big[\arctan s\Big]_0^{\infty}\\
&=(1-u)\pi
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle J=(1-u)\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $1\ge s\ge u\iff1-\dfrac{1+u}2\ge s-\dfrac{1+u}2\ge u-\dfrac{1+u}2$

WLOG choose $s-\dfrac{1+u}2=\dfrac{1-u}2\cdot\cos2t,0\le2u\le\pi\  \ \  \ (1)$

$ds=-2(1-u)\sin t\cos t$

$s=1\implies t=0; s=u\implies t=\dfrac\pi2$

$1-s=1-\dfrac{1+u}2-\dfrac{1-u}2\cdot\cos2t=\dfrac{1-u}2\cdot2\sin^2t\implies\sqrt{1-s}=\sqrt{1-u}\sin t$ by $(1)$

Similarly, $\sqrt{s-u}=\sqrt{1-u}\cos t$

Can you take it from here?